# Is the autoparallel equation same as the geodesic equation?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, geodesic, connections

My question may sound silly but i am self learning differential geometry using watching these lectures ([Lecture 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eVWUdcI2ho)) from 2015 by professor Frederic Schuller.

Can somebody please tell that the auto-parallel equation same as the geodesic equation?

Comment: 1. Could you please summarize the necessary definitions to make your question self-contained? 2. Offhand, "probably not". On a sphere, every great circle is parallel to a family of latitudes, and these latitudes are not geodesics.

Comment: @Andrew Hi! Maybe the question was edited, but it now reads as a question about *auto parallel* curves, not parallel ones. That is, $\nabla_{c'}c' = 0$.

Comment: @Catalin: A belated _Welcome_ to M.SE. Nice to see you! The question hasn't been edited; I just read carelessly. :)

Comment: what is the difference between the  auto parallel equation and and the geodesic equation @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: @Bogorovich: As Catalin Zara notes, if by "autoparallel equation" you mean $\nabla_{c'} c' = 0$, that's the same as the geodesic equation for $c$.

Comment: @Bogorovich: The lecture seems very interesting but it lasts for almost 90 minutes. I second Andrew's request that you summarize the relevant definitions. In particular, please carefully summarize the definitions of: autoparallel, autoparallely transported, and geodesic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot talk about geodesics until you have a notion of distance, and curvature is insufficient for that. However, in lecture 10 he introduces the metric tensor, and he shows that the geodesic equation for a given metric takes the form of an autoparallel equation for one specific curvature / connection / covariant derivative.

Answer (score 5):

Let there be given a [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) $(M,g)$ with a [connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(mathematics)) $\nabla$ that is compatible with the metric $g$ but not necessarily [torsion-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor). Let $\nabla^{LC}$ denote the [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection) for $g$. Then the [geodesic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) $\nabla^{LC}_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}=0$ and the auto-parallel equation $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}=0$ are *not* necessarily the same. They are the same iff the torsion tensor is totally antisymmetric. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/306927/2451) Phys.SE post for details.